# How to get a pointer to a member variable for memcpy

Tags: c++, var

edited for clarification;
why wont this work yet compile?

```
class Member{
public:
__int32 PublicInt;
}
Member x;
memcpy(&x.PublicInt,&ByteArray,sizeof(__int32));
```

is this not getting a pointer to the place where int is stored?

Comment: When you're copying an `int`, you should use `sizeof(int)`; when copying a `long` `sizeof(long)` etcetera. You're now mixing `int` and `__int32`.

Comment: @MSalters: isn't something like `sizeof(Into)` even better?

Comment: i am aware it was irrelevant to the question so i just typed it out quick.

Comment: I think you need to provide a more exact example because accessing a member variable pointer in the way you have done here will work absolutely fine.  You must have a different bug/typo in your actual code that "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick **[sample](http://ideone.com/pdlU5)** to help you understand:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
class Myclass
{
    public:
        char str2[40];

};

int main()
{
   char str1[]="Sample string";
   Myclass obj;
   memcpy(&(obj.str2),str1,strlen(str1)+1);
   std::cout<<obj.str2;

   return 0;
}
```

Hth :)

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is

```
int Into;
```

...then its address is:

```
&Into
```

Note that what you get with an array reference *is* the address, so if `ByteArray` is really a byte array, I suspect you've just misplaced the `&` in your `memcpy` and that this is what you want:

```
memcpy(&Into, ByteArray, sizeof(__int32));
```

I'd also recommend doing this:

```
memcpy(&Into, ByteArray, sizeof(Into));
```

...in case you change its type later.

Comment: yeh i know that but im talking about accessing a member variable.

Comment: @user: I don't *think* it makes any difference. Have you tried it with the `&` removed from `ByteArray` (assuming it really is an array)?

Comment: its a hypothetical bytearray its not part of the question its a char* array

Comment: @user: but it is part of the question if you pass its address wrong. No matter what its type is.

Comment: @user: If it's a `char *`, then you definitely don't want that `&` there. Say that `char *` is `cp`. `&cp` means the address ***of the pointer***. `cp` is the address the pointer points to, which is almost certainly what you want.